# cant retrieve data from select box while using its id

Tags: php, mysql

this is my select tag but in the grid while editing and adding i cannot retrieve country value only code value appears what shall i do nw?

```
<select name="country" id="country" >

<option value="" >select country</option>
<?php $select_query= mysql_query("Select * from country");
     while($select_query_array = mysql_fetch_array($select_query))
     {  
?>

<option value="<?php echo $select_query_array['code'];?>" <?php if($_POST['country']==$select_query_array['code']) { ?> selected="selected" <?php } ?> > <?php echo $select_query_array['country']; ?> </option>
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

Comment: show your full form here

Comment: It seems you're setting the options' value to an empty string

Answer (score 0):

**Ex:**

```
<select name="test">
    <option value="1|Test one">Test one</option>
    <option value="2|Test two">Test two</option>
</select>
```

And then:

```
$test = explode('|', $_POST['test']);
```

Then you'll end up with **$test[0] being "1" and $test[1] being "Test one".**

Comment: but i need to get database values into select box

Comment: what o/p exctly u want?

Comment: country value have to be inserted in to database but code value only displaying.,

Answer (score 0):

i presume you're using jquery..

try something like this:

```
$('#country option:selected').text()
```

Comment: my flexigrid only jquery.. i'm using this code in php and html only,,

Answer (score 0):

check this solution:-

```
<?php $select_query= mysql_query("Select * from country"); ?>
<select name="country" id="country" >
<option value="" >select country</option>
<?php
 while($row = mysql_fetch_array($select_query))
  {
   if($_POST['country']==$select_query_array['code'])
    $selected='selected="selected"';
   else
    $selected='';
   echo '<option value="'.$row['code'].'"'.$selected.' >'.$row['country'].'</option>';
?>
</select>
```

Comment: in tis code all the database values are not displaying in combo box then hz can i select it?

Comment: @user2720205 : i guess this is correct answer, u just need to change "$row['code']" with "$row['country']" if u want to country name for POSTing to next form.

Comment: @user2720205 if you choose these option value you will get the country_code which is feasible to store instead of country_name,when you need country_name you need to join country table upon country_code..

Comment: thanks for ur kind reply. i got proper output by changing second flexigrid php page..

Answer (score 0):

First remove your while loop only fetch data and then check your condition

```
<option value="<?php echo $select_query_array['code'];?>" <?=(isset($_POST['country']) && !empty($_POST['code']) && $_POST['country'] == $select_query_array['code']) ? $select_query_array['code'] : ""; ?> > <?php echo $select_query_array['code']; ?> </option>
```

Comment: tis lso shows code value only .. i need value of country column into the grid